# email COULD NOT FETCH error in react-native-twitter-signin library

Tags: react-native, twitter-login

While implementing twitter signin in react native with react-native-twitter-signin I have followed all steps from the documentation but I am not receiving user object in then() method. It throws an error in catch block. The error is following

Error: { NativeMap: {"email":"COULD_NOT_FETCH","userName":"osamaaer05","userID":"13540882326114024","name":"osamaeer05","authTokenSecret":"nymvUWPAnBnvvhfhbQ1IU1ojETUuJWvq01VCiLOZDn9","authToken":"1354088232611414024-425rd6PMkdQVk1YrP1gAiiBuwpc9"} }

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask . 

You should provide a reproduceable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If email is not required replace the function in node_modules/@react-native-twitter-signin/twitter-signin/android/src/main/java/com/rntwittersignin/twittersignin/TwitterSigninModule.java

```
@Override
 public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
 map.putString("email", "");
 promise.resolve(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem using the `react-native-twitter-signin/twitter-signin` to authenticate with `firebase`.

Similar to your error, mine also contains all necessary information (besides the email) for a successful login. So, I thought we could use the error for authentication.

As it turns out this is also proposed in the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login) published by firebase for JS. They offer a method called `credentialFromError()` which is also available for `react-native`.

With this information, I came up with the following code that lets me log in with twitter:

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import RNTwitterSignIn from '@react-native-twitter-signin/twitter-signin';


RNTwitterSignIn.init('XXX_API_KEY_XXX', 'XXX_API_SECRET_XXX').then(() =>
    console.log('Twitter SDK initialized'),
);

async function onTwitterButtonPress() {

    var twitterCredential;

    try {
        // Perform the login request
        const { authToken, authTokenSecret } = await RNTwitterSignIn.logIn();

        // Create a Twitter credential with the tokens
        twitterCredential = auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credential(authToken, authTokenSecret);

    } catch (e) {
        // Create a Twitter credential with the error       
        twitterCredential = auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credentialFromError(e);
    }

    return auth().signInWithCredential(twitterCredential);
}
```

P.S.: Not sure if the question is related to firebase, but I think it is still a helpful insight that the error does not mean that the authentication/login failed.